# Вылезает лишь окно с возможностью ввести текст,без виджета прокрутки(Scrollbar)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
text=Text(root,width=50,height=30,font='16')
scr=Scrollbar(root,command=text.yview)
text.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
text.grid(row=0,column=0)
text.grid(row=0,column=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо этого:

```
text.grid(row=0,column=0)
text.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

скорее всего должно было быть:

```
text.grid(row=0,column=0)
scr.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

Также для scr лучше указать, чтобы он расширялся по вертикали, иначе он будет минимального размера:

```
scr.grid(row=0,column=1, sticky=N+S)
```

`N+S` - "север+юг" - т.е. как раз растяжение по вертикали.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
text=Text(root,width=50,height=30,font='16')
scr=Scrollbar(root,command=text.yview)
scr.grid()
text.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set)
text.grid(row=0,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```